# Opening Unsupported RAW Files

Tags: raw, nikon-d600

OK, maybe I'm rushing it a little but I've been shooting RAW+JPEG with a production [Nikon D600](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/nikon/d600/summary) and, well, there is no RAW converter available yet, not even from Nikon.

**Is it possible to open these RAW files without writing a decoder myself?** I realize it cannot be *optimal* since the camera is not known but considering it uses a standard CMOS sensor with Bayer-Filter, just having the 14-bit samples per pixels would be good enough to produce an image from it.

Comment: It is about time someone made a standard RAW format

Comment: @silenT_Thunder - Google the acronym "DNG" for such a format...

Comment: Did you try something like RawTherapee?

Comment: @Itai: You can use one of the open source RAW editors. Most things that run on dcraw will usually open new but otherwise unsupported version of RAW from the likes of Nikon, Canon, etc. I think dcraw generally ignores what it can't handle, and keeps trying to process when it can. I've even been able to open corrupted RAW files that ACR/LR wouldn't open with an open source RAW editor, and at times even save a working copy.

Comment: JoanneC: Some people see DNG as a second coming but it really cannot be universal. It's already hacked for Fuji cameras (there are special fields in the header) because DNG is only data and someone still needs to define the process. Until a file-format can include conversion-logic, it is pointless to have a standard container.

Comment: Strange, I *had* dcraw I know... Guess I'll have to get a fresh copy.

Comment: @Itai - Specification is here: http://www.adobe.com/ca/products/photoshop/extend.displayTab2.html and bear in mind, it is TIFF based which is true for most, if not all, major raw formats. At any rate, the specification distinctly includes support for private vendor data for the purposes of their own converters. I think it's the closest thing around to a universal format and haven't heard a real compelling reason for a vendor to not use it.

Comment: @Itai - It's also the recommended format for Library of Congress storage for the purpose of long term archival.

Comment: JoanneC: Yes, I am very familiar with DNG and TIFF as well. The compelling reason not to use is that there is no compelling reason to use it. Vendor data in the format is meaningless if there is no way to specify how to interpret it. Otherwise, you end up updating DNG converter each time a new camera appears. Actually, that is pretty much what happens lately.

Comment: @Itai - I was processing K-5 DNG files well before the updates from Adobe to handle the PEF files, so not sure I buy that argument. While you state that vendor data in the format is useless, you haven't given a compelling reason for it to exist in the first place. The vendor probably has a strong desire to lock you in with that data, but that's not a strong argument for the consumer in my book. Net effect, I still haven't heard a strong argument against DNG beyond "I don't want to do it."

Comment: JoanneC: Unless the D600 will be capable of producing DNG files natively in-camera, I don't see how DNG actually solves Itai's problem. The question was how to handle D600 NEF files before software is updated to support it. Even if you wanted to convert to DNG, you still need to be able to handle the original native RAW. Generally speaking the changes to raw file formats between cameras is pretty minor, the bulk of the format remains unchanged (breakage is usually due to new unknown values at known locations). An OSS RAW editor is really the only solution.

Comment: @jrista - It doesn't solve his problem, that entire sequence stems from the very first comment to the question and my simple response to that. Feel free to move the whole thing to chat, which is what  this is really, but his question does somewhat prove the point about the usefulness of DNG...

Comment: Yeah, I think DNG could be the solution, if it was natively supported by all cameras. At the moment, the "move to chat" link isn't appearing...and I don't think we have a mod tool to do that at any time yet. Guess we need a couple more comments. :P

Comment: JoanneC: Yes, I'd me happy to explain you what the problem is with such a data formats on chat. It's kind too long for this comment but modern cameras have given my very concrete examples of why standard data without standard process does not scale.

Comment: I've got a D600 and it shipped with a copy of ViewNX 2, which can be used to open the RAW files. You can also download this software off the Nikon site. [http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Imaging-Software/NVNX/ViewNX.html](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Imaging-Software/NVNX/ViewNX.html)

Comment: I just bought the D600, it comes with Nikon ViewNX 2 which will open and edit files. However the only outputs (Convert files) listed are .TIFF and .JPG, I wish it would out put to .DNG. I was hoping for more.

Comment: I have been able to open and process using the latest version of NX2. I save them as Tiffs and import to lightroom.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might try simply altering the EXIF data in the images so the camera model is something your conversion software supports.

I just did some experimentation with an image from my D300 that proved successful.  Changing the model field from `NIKON D300` to `NIKON D900` (fictional, for now) made AfterShot Pro reject the image, but changing it to `NIKON D700` worked fine.  I don't imagine the raw formats among the cameras are all that different, and a quick eyeball comparison of the original and altered files as ASP displayed them didn't show any visible difference.

**EDIT:**  Just found a D600 NEF and did the same experiment.  Worked fine.

The D600 doesn't appear to break any ground when it comes to how the images are stored, so find its closest supported relative and use that.

Comment: Great. Turned D600 files into D3X ones :)

Comment: But how can you edit the Exif when the raw file is not supported? I tried to open an unsupported NEF with Adobe Ps and Br,  I also tried the Opanda IExif with no luck... how else can you edit the Exif data?

Comment: @Omne:  You use software that just edits the EXIF and doesn't care what's in it.  I did mine on the command line using [ExifTool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool).

Comment: Anybody an idea why exiftool denies to change -model while -sonymodelid is changed properly? 
Tried to change ILCE-7RM4 to ILCE-7RM3 and only sonymodelid was updated while model was left intact.

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem opening D600 NEFs in Image View Plus More. It is based on dcraw, but it gives you a GUI to tweak the development settings and once converted you get all the features imgview+ have - such as lens dedistortion, colour tweaking, transformations, retouching, etc..