# How to change camera model with exiftool?

Tags: metadata, exiftool

I bought a Nikon D600 only to realise that Lightroom 4 can't read the RAW format that it shoots in. I've done some research and found that some people use the Exiftool to change the model and then Lightroom will open the files. But, they don't really say *exactly* how to do this... I have never worked with a command prompt program, so I need to know the exact steps.

Comment: http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/post/42653559 LightRoom 4.2 supports D600 raw files :-)

Comment: There is a free upgrade to Lightroom 4.2, so this question is already out-dated and you don't have to worry about it anymore.

Comment: But it might be useful in the future.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone. Itai - not sure how I missed that, been struggling for a week now :-( Yippeeeee!!!

Answer (score 11):

`% exiftool -Model='Kodak Hawkeye Instamatic' image.nef`

Further discussion on how to open unsupported files in [Opening Unsupported RAW Files](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27253).