# How can I get Canon 6D's RAW format to work in OS X Lion?

Tags: raw, macintosh, canon-6d

I recently got a Canon 6D, and though it says that OS X Lion has native support for its RAW format, iPhoto reports that the file format is unknown. It works fine using Adobe Lightroom, but it would be convenient to be able to import to iPhoto on my old laptop.

I run OS X Lion version 10.8.2 and iPhoto 8.1.2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening Unsupported RAW Files](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27253/opening-unsupported-raw-files)

Comment: @Itai - No, I don't think this is a duplicate. The format is supported, he just needs to do some updates and this question may help people find similar answers in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update your copy of iPhoto to get the update that supports the Canon 6D. See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4757 for some detail, especially note that the raw update 4.03 has an asterisk to a note at the bottom: "*Aperture version 3.4 or later, or iPhoto version 9.4 or later, is required to install this update.*"

Comment: Thanks, I didn't miss your answer, and I gave you an upvote :) Although, I was hoping for a put-this-driver-in-this-folder-kind-of-solution :)

Comment: @Jørgen - It is a driver thing, but in order to get it, you need iPhoto to be updated...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the DPP software that came in the box with your body? The Canon supplied software is updated when it ships.

While I don't like the workflow of DPP, for some tasks, it works better and faster than either Aperture 3 or Lightroom 4.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried it yet, as I was hoping for some way to enable raw support in iPhoto, but I guess I'll have to settle with some other application.

Comment: I expect that there will be an update for the 6D "real soon now" from Apple. Of course RSN is impossible to predict or connect to a real calendar.

Comment: @Jorgen - Did you _*miss*_ the link I posted to Apple only 8 hours before you responded? It's pretty obvious how to get it in iPhoto: update it. Sheesh.

Comment: @PatFarrell - If, by "real soon now," you mean 10 days ago, then yes, yes I think you can predict it... http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1604 (please see my answer as to the minimum software requirements for this update).